# TcpClient Streamreader doesn't block thread when running program from exe

Tags: c#, tcpclient, streamreader

I'm building a small application that reads IRC chat messages. Everything is working fine
both in release and debug as long as I run it from my IDE (Jetbrains Rider).

What I expect to happen and what happens when I run the program from my IDE is that `_readStream.ReadLine();` should block the thread until a message comes in. For some reason when I run my app from the executable file the thread does not get blocked and the message `"I should have been blocked"` gets printed (look at code below). This happens for both release and debug executable file.

Why does this happen?

UPDATE:
IOException gives this message `Can't read line, Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.`
I Have tried to add it to exceptions in firewall and inbound and outbound rules, still no dice.

```cs
public void Connect()
{
    _tcpClient.Connect(_ip, _port);
    _readStream = new StreamReader(_tcpClient.GetStream());
    _writeStream = new StreamWriter(_tcpClient.GetStream());
}

public string ReadMessage()
{
    return _readStream.ReadLine();
}

protected void Run() 
{
    while (IsRunning())
    {
        try
        {
            string message = ReadMessage();
            if (message == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I should have been blocked");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is `IsRunning()` doing?. Is there a reason you aren't catching other exceptions and logging them?

Comment: Make your troubleshooting life easier and do NOT use string.IsNullOrEmpty in this case. Returning an empty string (`""`) vs. returning `null` has a different meaning with regard to TextReader.ReadLine, the former just being an empty line being received, the latter indicating EOS. Since you just use string.IsNullOrEmpty, you are unable to differentiate between these two possibilities, thus leaving you with less knowledge about what's going on...

Comment: @DavidL IsRunning() just returns a bool. I'm catching IOException because that is the error StreamReader returns if it cant read.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace The program only prints when running from exe file. So you mean I might be receiving a message that counts as empty even though it's not?

Comment: @objectnabb, well, are you implictly suggesting that the basic and common-as-bread function `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is broken? ;-) An empty string is an empty string. There are no non-empty strings that would be empty strings. I also did not mean to say that you necessarily _must_ have gotten an empty string. Read my previous comment carefully...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace ah You mean I should test if it's empty or null? :)

Comment: Yes. I don't know with certainty whether it will reveal some useful hints or not in your specific case, but generally regarding the ReadLine method, an empty string should always be treated differently than null, because these two values tell fundamentally different things about the state of the TextReader (and its underlying stream).

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I Updated the question, it's null. I only used this when I started to get errors (When running the exe) I didn't think it could be null since is should block until it got a message?

Comment: Getting null here probably(!) means the other endpoint closed the socket. If true, i don't know why the other side behaves that way. You will need to compare what you did differently when you ran your program in the IDE. You will also need to account for program settings, firewall/antivirus settings, host OS settings, etc... basically stuff that is related to network configuration and network traffic both at the level of your program, the IDE, and the host OS your program is operating in...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247857/discussion-between-objectnabb-and-myskullcaveisadarkplace).

Comment: Guessing either the other side closed the socket or the KeepAlive timeout expired because no messages. TCP connections don't stay open forever, you need to *use* them or set a KeepAlive.

Comment: @Charlieface So the other side only closes the socket when I launch my app through the executable?